# Can't display the output of a search on another component

Tags: reactjs

Im having problems at the result component i can't render the filteredData, at result this.props.dataToRender ain't working thats the problem.

I have all the logic already, but when trying to display the result of the search on another component i'm getting no information.

If i execute the code on the app component i get the result of the search but if i try to pass it as props i don't get a result at the other side.

```
  state = { data: [], filteredData: [], value: "" };

  async componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://tenjoucesar.github.io/data.json")
      .then(response => response.data)
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ data });
        console.log(this.state.data);
      });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    const { value, data } = this.state;
    e.preventDefault();
    let email = value;
    const filtered = data.filter(e => e.email === email); 
    this.setState({ filteredData: filtered });

  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
  }

InfomData = person => {
    return (
      <div className="result" key={person.email}>
        <h3 >
          {person.name}, &nbsp;{person.age}
        </h3>
        <p className="paragraph--result">{person.notes}</p>
      </div>
    );
  };

render() {
    const { filteredData } = this.state;
    const dataToRender = filteredData.map(e => this.InfomData(e));
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Nav />
        <Switch>
          <>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Header} />
            <Search
              component={Search}
              handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}
              handleChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
              value={this.props.value}
              type={this.props.email}
            />
            <Route exact path="/" component={Reverse} />
            <Route
              path="/result"
              component={Result}
              dataToRender={dataToRender}
            />
          </>
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Here at Result component i tried moving informData and the const dataToRender but didn't work.

```
class Result extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="section-result">
        <div className="container--result">
          <h1 className="heading-primary--result">Results</h1>
          <p className="paragraph--results">
            Look at the result below to see the details of the person you're
            searched for.
          </p>
        </div>
        {this.props.dataToRender}
        <TryAgain />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I just want to get the result on the result component, i had tried with all that i found, nothing worked.
Could someone tell me what do i have to do ? I'm sorry still learning about react

Comment: Can you point the exact place of problem?

Comment: Sure, i'm having problems at the result component i can't render  the filteredData, at result this.props.dataToRender ain't working thats the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Modify the `Route` to this

```
 <Route
    path="/result"
    render={() => <Result dataToRender={dataToRender} />}
  />
```

Since you have to inject props to a component, this is the way

*Pass Route's `render` an arrow function with component and customProps*

**EDIT**

If you also need the `history, location, search` props that are passed by default when we use `<Route path="/" component={Something} />` then pass them explicitly

```
<Route 
   path="/result"
   render = {(props) => <Result dataToRender={dataToRender} {...props} /> }
/>
```

Comment: Wow you helped me a lot, i was trying without succes, now i understand Thank you!